# Run multiple executables all at once

Tags: c, linux, sockets, terminal, executable

I have a C Sockets application, different executables of which must run at same time all at once, preferably in different terminals. How do I do it?
For example, there are four exes, ./one, ./two, ./three, ./four.

I want them to be run in different linux terminals without slightest of time difference. How can I do it?

Comment: Even if you manage to start all of your programs at the exact same time, they *will* sooner or later execute out of synchronization as the OS scheduler will run them at different times on different cores and for different intervals; they will even run at different speeds due to memory caching and such. You aren't saying why these need to be run "without slightest of time difference" but that's the issue you actually need to address. [What is the problem you are actually trying to solve here?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: runnign on three different terminals or you want to direct the out put to three different terminals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will always be at least a "slightest of time difference".
Just have your exe's agree on a time to proceed and just sleep until that time before doing whatever it is that they need to do.

Answer (score 0):

You will never run several process at the same time. If you need just to start them nearly at the same time for testing purposes, then, probably, easiest way is to start terminal emulator to run your each of your executable. If you have `xorg` installed, then you can open `xterm` and run there something like this:

```
xterm -e "./app1; /bin/bash" & xterm -e "app2; /bin/bash" & ...
```

where the /bin/bash is called to prevent closing new `xterm`s after your application will be finished.

I'm not `bash` expert so this works on my machine and I can't be sure about exactly this string will work with older or newer `bash` or `sh` pr with another terminal emulator. But you always can write something similar.

Answer (score 0):

To run simultaneously you can do something like this:

```
     "declare -a cmd=(./first ./second ./third); for i in ${cmd[@]}; do exec $i wait & done"
```

This can help you to automate your task. Keep your commands on array, exec them. It'll run all the processes on background and will start trying to run them simultaneously.